# How do I configure rootless containers so that they can reach the host?

Tags: podman

I'm trying out podman as an alternative to docker and I'm having an issue where I can't seem to reach the host from my containers.

Normally in docker, I'd point anything that wants to talk to the host to `172.17.0.1`, but that address doesn't seem to be working with rootless podman.

It's possible that there's something very basic that I'm missing here...

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be `172.17.0.1`, is it? On my system it's `172.18.0.1`. Did you check `ip addr` on the host  to make sure that's the right IP address?

Comment: For podman? I'm not seeing any additional adapters.

Answer (score 5):

#### Update 12 January 2024

Use the option `--network=pasta:--map-gw` if you use the **pasta** network driver. Soon **pasta** will  become the default network driver in Podman instead of **slirp4netns**  (see Jira issue [RUN-1953](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/RUN/issues/RUN-1953?filter=allopenissues)).

#### Old answer

Use the option `--network slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true`

Here is an example:

Open two terminal windows.

In **terminal 1** run these commands to start a web server listening on port 8080 on the host

```
$ mkdir dir
$ echo hello > dir/file.txt
$ cd dir
$ python3 -m http.server --bind 127.0.0.1 8080
Serving HTTP on 127.0.0.1 port 8080 (http://127.0.0.1:8080/) ...
```

In **terminal 2** download the file *file.txt* with rootless Podman

```
$ podman run \
    --rm \
    --network slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true \
    docker.io/library/fedora \
      curl -s 10.0.2.2:8080/file.txt
hello
```

In **terminal 1** this line was printed

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2022 08:27:54] "GET /file.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

##### About the system

```
$ podman --version
podman version 4.3.1
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 37 (Thirty Seven)
$
```

#### References

Quote from the **podman run** [man page](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html#network-mode-net):

*allow_host_loopback=true|false: Allow slirp4netns to reach the host loopback IP (default is 10.0.2.2 or the second IP from slirp4netns cidr subnet when changed, see the cidr option below). The default is false.*

Answer (score 1):

Erik's answer is correct. However, it is good to understand that containers attached to host network with `--network=host` have access to any service that is attached to the host's local loopback address.

If this is *not* OK for you, one workaround is to:

1. Setup a dummy interface with IP `xx.yy.zz.kk/32` and a route (`ip link add` or with `netplan`)
2. Define `outbound_addr=xx.yy.zz.kk` in `.config/containers/containers.conf`
3. Create firewall rules to limit access service bound to the host's local loopback address
4. Create a firewall rule to masquerade the `xx.yy.zz.kk` IP if the container needs to connect outside the host

### Create dummy interface

**Manually**

```
# load kernel module for dummy interface
modprobe dummy

# Create virtual interface
ip link add dm0 type dummy

# Add IP address
ip address add 192.168.50.1/32 dev dm0

# Add route
route add 192.168.50.1 dev dm0
```

**With netplan**

For systems using `netplan` edit `/etc/netplan/netplan.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd  
  dummy-devices:
    dm0:
      optional: true
      addresses:
        - 192.168.50.1/32
```

and run `netplan try`.

### Configure `slirp4netns`

Set `outbound_addr` in `~/.config/containers/containers.conf` for the podman user. The pod's traffic will now appear to come from the set IP.

```
[engine]
network_cmd_options=["allow_host_loopback=true", "enable_ipv6=false", "outbound_addr=192.168.50.1"]
```

### Firewall rules

The traffic from pods will come through local loopback device (`dev lo` in `nftables`), but with the set IP.

**Filter the traffic from the pod's IP**

E.g. allow access only to TCP port 9100. (these are just an example).

```
table ip filter {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

    ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop}

    # loopback interface, notice the additional "saddr" specifier
    iifname lo ip saddr 127.0.0.0/8 accept comment "accept loopback"
    ip saddr 192.168.50.1 tcp dport 9100  accept
    ip saddr 192.168.50.1 drop
   }
}
```

**Add masquerade**

```
table ip nat {

  chain postrouting {
   type nat hook postrouting priority 100 ;
   ip saddr $net_pods oif $eth_lan masquerade
  }    
} # table NAT
```