# How do I send emails from a container using an SMTP server on the host?

Tags: java, smtp, podman

I have an SMTP server listening on localhost port 25 on a host machine.  There is an application running in a Podman container (started by a non-root user) that needs to automatically send emails to registered users.  Right now, attempting to send emails results in a `Connection refused` error.  How can we set up the container to work with the host's mail server?

The application was able to send emails prior to being containerized, so I'm guessing there's some networking configuration that we don't have set up correctly.

Here is an anonymized version of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-amazoncorretto-8 as maven
LABEL APPLICATION="Application"
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn clean
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM tomcat:8.5.75-jdk8-corretto
#ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:MetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Xss512k"

#Move over the War file from previous build step
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY --from=maven /app/target/application.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/application.war

# enables tomcat to read config from environment properties
RUN echo 'org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource' >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties

# copy in server.xml and web.xml customizations used for HTTPS
COPY server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
COPY web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/web.xml



EXPOSE 8080
# expose port 8001 if you want to do remote debugging of the container
#EXPOSE 8001
EXPOSE 8443
# smtp
EXPOSE 25
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so your SMTP server is on the host, and the containerized app can't reach it. First thing, containers have their own network space, so "localhost" inside the container isn't the host's localhost. To fix this, you've got a few options:

1. Use Host Network: Run the container with the host's network stack. This is the quickest fix but less secure. Use podman run --network=host ... when starting your container. This makes your container use the host's network, so localhost in the container maps to the host's localhost.
2. Configure SMTP to Listen on All Interfaces: By default, your SMTP server might only listen to localhost (127.0.0.1). Change its config to listen on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Be aware of the security implications though; this exposes your SMTP server to all networks the host is connected to.
3. Container-to-Host Communication: If you don't want to use the host network, find out the host's internal IP address in the container network (often it's something like 10.0.2.2, but it can vary). Configure your app to use this IP for SMTP.

Comment: Appreciate the info.  Quick question on your third suggestion: I've been trying `host.containers.internal`, which I understand to be equivalent to using the host IP, without success.  Will that approach work if the SMTP server is only listening on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to localhost on the host is not allowed by default when using *pasta* or *slirp4netns* but it is possible to enable it.

In case you use *pasta*, add the **podman run** option `--network=pasta:--map-gw`

In case you use *slirp4netns*, add the **podman run** option `--network=slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true`

To connect to a SMTP server running on the host that is listening on `127.0.0.1:25`, connect to `10.0.2.2:25`

#### References

- [podman-networking-docs](https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-networking-docs?tab=readme-ov-file#outbound-tcpudp-connections-to-the-hosts-localhost) some documentation about rootless Podman networking (written by me)
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580507/757777) (written by me) to the Stackoverflow question "*How do I configure rootless containers so that they can reach the host?*"
- Podman GitHub discussion thread [*How to send emails via a TCP socket listening on localhost on the host?*](https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/11106) (thread started by me)