Podman container can't access a service on host via host-gateway
I run my container with the flag --add-host=host.containers.internal:host-gateway. Application inside the container can't reach a service on 127.0.0.1:11434 on my main host, but the app can reach it if i add the flag --network=host.
Logs from the container
Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:11434 ssl:default [Connection refused]


IIRC, the --add-host=... part should be unnecessary. From within the container, we should use host.containers.internal instead of localhost /  127.0.0.1 to refer to the docker host.

@Turing85 i know i can use either. But i tried host.containers.internal and a random IP and realized my environment variables doesn't work, the service still send requests to 127.0.0.1

Seems to be a configuration issue within the application then. Without seeing the relevant code, I am afraid we cannot help.

@Turing85 i don't need to set any environment variables, i was wrong. It's harder to find the problem, because i ran the container as systemd service on nixos before, so --add-host=host.containers.internal:host-gateway this flag didn't cause any problems. Now i am trying to run from shell and this flag causes the following error: Error: failed to create new hosts file: unable to replace "host-gateway" of host entry "host.containers.internal:host-gateway": host containers internal IP address is empty.

@Turing85 there is the code https://github.com/open-webui/open-webui/blob/main/Dockerfile. I can't access ENV OLLAMA_BASE_URL from inside my container.

@Turing85 i tried to curl from inside the container curl host.containers.internal:11434 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: host.containers.internal. Maybe i didn't understand you right? I didn't use --add-host for this container

I am not sure about the --add-host=.... . I tried it on one of my sample projects (with podman) and it worked without. But it might be that I configured something somewhere in podman and forgot I did it, so now it "simply works". The important part is that the application calls host.containers.internal. not localhost.

@Turing85 my be firewall, but i disabled it. Thanks for your attention, anyway

If you run rootless podman, you might need --network=pasta:--map-gw or
--network slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74579092/how-do-i-configure-rootless-containers-so-that-they-can-reach-the-host
